# MyBoy! GBA stops/freezes when I load games?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald, my-boy

The MyBoy! emulator sometimes stops working for no reason. Most of the time I ignore this, and just load my game, but this time I was playing Pokemon Emerald on the emulator, I was at the Battle Factory and I saved right before the emulator stopped working.

I loaded the save file, and when I did, it just stopped working again. I just thought "whatever", and loaded it again. But the same thing happened!

I did this a couple more times, and decided to see if it would freeze if I didn't load it at all. I waited for about 5 minutes (That's a lot more time than it usually takes to stop working) and it didn't stop.

I loaded it again, and noticed that it stops when the guy says "Before we resume your challenge, I must save the game.", so I waited on the text before that one, and to my surprise, it didn't stop. I loaded one of my emulator save states and waited. It didn't stop.

How do I fix this annoying issue?